# Como obter apenas um resultado do git log entre o intervalo fornecido?

Tags: git

Como posso filtrar apenas um único  commint do git log ?

Exemplo:

```
git log --after=2017-10-02T13:40:56
```

Com isso eu consigo todos os commits depois dessa data, como posso obter apenas o primeiro commit depois dessa data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conseguir resolver utilizando **-Quantidade**

Exemplo:

```
git log -1 --after=2017-10-02T13:40:56
```

Dessa forma e mostrado apenas o primeiro depois.